# How to call <script type="text/javascript"> from button

Tags: javascript, call

I have this situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//massage.book.me/iframe/pm_loader_v2.php?width=960&url=//massage.book.me&theme=bootstrap__square_rainbow__colored_light&layout=bootstrap__square_rainbow&timeline=modern&mode=auto&mobile_redirect=0&hidden_steps=event,unit&event=1&unit=1"></script>
```

How can I have a button call it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is that script supposed to? `<script type="text/javascript">` loads a javascript resource. that doesn't look very much like a javascript resource

Comment: You cannot **call** a `<script>` element. Those elements are executed immediately by the browser. Please *clarify* what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Accept the answer that worked for you, to let others know if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically include(load) an external javascript file to the page on certain button `click` event:

*html part:*

```
<button class="getscript">Load script</button>
```

*js part:*

```
document.querySelector('button.getscript').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    script.src = "//massage.book.me/iframe/pm_loader_v2.php?width=960&url=//massage.book.me&theme=bootstrap__square_rainbow__colored_light&layout=bootstrap__square_rainbow&timeline=modern&mode=auto&mobile_redirect=0&hidden_steps=event,unit&event=1&unit=1";

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: If this is really what the OP wants (pretty unclear from the question), then it's a duplicate of [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/950087/218196) and should be closed as such. In general, please don't encourage low quality questions by answering them.

Comment: @FelixKling, let's wait to see what the OP really intended, then you may close it

Comment: Tks RomanPerekhrest. I will be back in office tomorrow where I will be able to try. I will post what happen but I got the idea. 

*** For the records if human been was not greedy as Felix this planet would be much better. I believe he don't get the main idea of GNU when he stated "...don't encourage low quality questions by answering them."